# Google App Engine - Endpoint is not validating GeoPt.class range

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, geopoints

Google App Engine - Endpoint is not validating GeoPt.class range when frontend sends as JSON with latitude/longitude value as out of range values. But while reading from datastore, it is getting validated and giving Exception. Do we need to manually validate or any work-around is there?

For instance, JSON from front-end

```
{
"latitude ": -12.983474,
"longitude": 195.098763
}
```

Expected Output: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Longitude must be between -180 and 180.

But, actually, Endpoint parses into GeoPt without above exception.

Comment: How is the GeoPt being constructed when sending the request?

Comment: As a JSON from front-end like shown above.